# Getting started with Nutch and Solr: where's Solr's conf/ directory?

Tags: solr, nutch

I'm trying to get started with Nutch (v 1.7) and Solr (v 4.3.1). I'm following this tutorial: http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchTutorial

I'm confused by [step 6](http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchTutorial#A6._Integrate_Solr_with_Nutch) where I'm told to copy a Nutch schema file into one of Solr's directories.

> **6. Integrate Solr with Nutch**
>
> We have both Nutch and Solr installed and setup correctly. And Nutch
>   already created crawl data from the seed URL(s). Below are the steps
>   to delegate searching to Solr for links to be searchable:
>
> cp ${NUTCH_RUNTIME_HOME}/conf/schema.xml
>   ${APACHE_SOLR_HOME}/example/solr/conf/

The problem is that `${APACHE_SOLR_HOME}/example/solr/conf/` doesn't exist.  `/example/solr/` only contains

```
README.txt  
bin     
collection1 
solr.xml
zoo.cfg
```

Does anyone know how to proceed? Should I *create* an `./example/solr/conf` directory and copy the Nutch files to that?

Many thanks for you help.

Comment: look at the path to the directory to have if correct. may not be correct:`${APACHE_SOLR_HOME}`, the correct is `/bla/bla/bla/example/solr/conf/`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are on Solr 4.x, you will have conf inside collection1, you should be able to do following:

```
cp ${NUTCH_RUNTIME_HOME}/conf/schema.xml ${APACHE_SOLR_HOME}/example/solr/collection1/conf/
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this, but then I got another error: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Plugin init failure for [schema.xml] fieldType "text": Plugin init failure for [schema.xml] analyzer/filter: Error loading class 'solr.EnglishPorterFilterFactory'

Comment: Nutch comes with a separate schema file for Solr 4.X Copy the schema-solr4.xml file, replacing the existing schema.xml file in your Solr directory.

Answer (score 1):

I think my mistake was to use version 4.3.1 of Solr with this particular Nutch tutorial. Previous versions of Solr, like 3.6.2, have a `conf` directory where the tutorial says they should. I think the tutorial was written with v 3.6.2 in mind.

I've switched to Solr v. 3.6.2, and now things are running more smoothly.

Answer (score 1):

I am trying to integrate Apache Nutch 1.7 with Apache Solr 3.6.2 and there is this line, right after the line you mentioned:

```
Copy exactly in 351 line: 

<field name="_version_" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

Now I am confused as the schema.xml copied from the Nutch directory has only 124 lines. Where to paste that line??

Thank you!

Comment: This is not the answer to the question

Comment: I am asking a follow-up question to the given question. Since the asker said they faced no problems after downgrading to Solr 3.6.2.